# Run SQL pre-defined function stored in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which stores a SQL predefined function, like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2012-08-21 00:16:41.993', 101)` in a row/column. While retrieving the result from table, it should run the function and give the final outcome as "2012-08-21", instead right now it returns the same function statement. I am running `select (select RunDate from RunDate)` and using SQL server database.

Kindly help!!

Comment: Adding to the same question, as aaron descibe its run fine for a single row. 
But how can i get multiple row's like 

`DECLARE @x TABLE(sql NVARCHAR(255)); 
INSERT @x(sql) SELECT N'CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ''2012-08-21 00:16:41.993'', 101)'; 
INSERT @x(sql) SELECT N'CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ''2012-08-18 00:16:41.993'', 101)'; 

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' + sql FROM @x; 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql; 

it's always give me a single result-set, result is : **2012-08-18** 
My question is, how can i get both the record in single result set?like :2012-08-21 
2012-08-18`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this. You can't just nest expressions and have SQL evaluate the output...

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(sql NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x(sql) SELECT N'CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ''2012-08-21 00:16:41.993'', 101)';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' + sql FROM @x;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this (adjust accordingly):

```
DECLARE @predef VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(1000);
SELECT  @predef = (SELECT top 1 Value FROM Parameters Where Name = 'MYFUNC');

SET @sqlquery = 'select ' + @predef + ' from SomeTable';
EXECUTE ( @sqlquery );
```

One tip: here be dragons. Beware of SQL Injection.

Comment: This doesn't parse FYI. First line has `SELECT @predef = SELECT` which doesn't work. Drop the second `SELECT`. Second line constructs a query that has an opening parenthesis but not a closing one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It was the hurry, it left the declarations out (and other few pointed details). I hope OP gets the point. Please revise, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't the down-voter though. Also be careful on line 3 - if Name isn't a key it could end up with the subquery returned more than one value error. You already have SELECT, why do you need a subquery?